# What do negative DEM values mean?

Tags: dem, bhuvan

My DEM elevation values varies from -255 to 81.

What does the negative values imply?

I have downloaded the dem from BHUVAN.

About 90 % of values fall in negative category.

How can I convert these values to positive?

Comment: You would have to find out what the range of your DEM implies, then normalize it.  Do you have any more info on the dataset?

Comment: Are you referring to the Cartosat DEM and allready checked the documentation? http://bhuvan-noeda.nrsc.gov.in/download/download/tools/document/CartoDEMReadme_v1_u1_23082011.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The negative values usually implies that the Z values are below a reference Z= 0 defined spot for sea level ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_level) for more explanations).

Should you really wish to have them positive (which i think is a bad idea), you would just have to add at least the minimum value of your area (255) to your dem with a constant value raster, resetting here your altimetric range from 0 (-255+255) to 336 (81+255).

Make sure those are not bad values ! If you see it's abnormal, you will have to do a "Fill" operation instead, which will help keeping the "good" Z values and recompute "bad" Z values ([see here for Arcgis](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=3914&pid=3910&topicname=Creating_a_depressionless_DEM) or [here for ILWIS](http://spatial-analyst.net/ILWIS/htm/ilwisapp/fill_sinks_functionality.htm)).